# Using variable declared in one method to open webpage in another method

Tags: ruby, methods, web-scraping, open-uri

I am working on a CLI Project and trying to open up a web page by using url variable declared in another method.

```
def self.open_deal_page(input)
  index = input.to_i - 1
  @deals = PopularDeals::NewDeals.new_deals
  @deals.each do |info|
  d = info[index]
  @product_url = "#{d.url}"
  end
  @product_url.to_s
  puts "They got me!"
end

def self.deal_page(product_url)
  #self.open_deal_page(input)
  deal = {}
  html = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@product_url))
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
  deal[:name] = doc.css(".dealTitle h1").text.strip
  deal[:discription] = doc.css(".textDescription").text.strip
  deal[:purchase] = doc.css("div a.button").attribute("href")
  deal
  #binding.pry
end
```

but I am receiving this error.

```
  `open': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

any possible solution? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: It's odd that you're declaring these as `self.x` instead of just `x`, as that makes them class methods, not instance methods. Normally when designing a component like this you'll want these to be instance methods so instance variables like `@deals` are local to the instance in question. If these are just stand-alone methods then there's no reason for the `self.` prefix, but you should also avoid using `@`-style instance variables. Instead pass through any necessary variables as arguments to your method. You're already doing this but referencing the variable incorrectly.

Comment: @tadman Thank you so much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning your `@product_url` within your `open_deal_page` method, because now you're returning `puts "They got me!"`, and also note that your `product_url` is being created inside your `each` block, so, it won't be accessible then, try creating it before as an empty `string` and then you can return it.

```
def open_deal_page(input)
  ...
  # Create the variable
  product_url = ''
  # Assign it the value
  deals.each do |info|
    product_url = "#{info[index].url}"
  end
  # And return it
  product_url
end
```

In your `deal_page` method tell to Nokogiri to open the product_url that you're passing as argument.

```
def deal_page(product_url)
  ...
  html = Nokogiri::HTML(open(product_url))
  ...
end
```

Comment: Glad to help you.